# I'm unfamiliar with how to convert old SQL join commands to modern code. *=/ =*

Tags: sql, legacy-code, legacy-database

I've been working on a little project that is including a lot of code renovation so to speak. I have a basic familiarity with the old sql join symbols, most of which I picked up from stackoverflow, however I'm noticing a lot of the structure surrounding is very different than what I'm familiar with. I'm basically stumped on code that is setup similar to this as far as converting it to modern SQL code.
I'd like to make this relevant to other people but I assume that most software would have been updated years ago. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
If @SelectLevel = '' Or @SelectLevel = 'B'
Select @SQLCmd =
    'SELECT Stop_Number, ''B'' AS Inv_Type, Inv_Desc, ' +
        'Box_Number AS Item_Number, BOX.Company_ID, BOX.Department_ID, BOX.Group_Id, BOX.Section_Id, ' +
        'BOX.Media_Code, BOX.Location_Current, BOX.Location_Home, BOX.Hold_Status, BOX.Record_Type, ' +
        'BOX.Alternate_Id, BOX.Description1, BOX.Retention_Code, BOX.Retention_type, BOX.Retention_Disposal, ' + 
        'BOX.Description2, BOX.Description3, ' + 
        'Reservation_Status, BOX.Disposition_Status ' +
    'FROM BOX, DISPOSITION_MEMO, (SELECT Item_Type, Item_Number, MAX(Reservation_Process_Status) AS ' +
    'Reservation_Status FROM RESERVATION GROUP BY Item_Type, Item_Number) AS RESV, ' +
    '(SELECT Ele_Text AS Inv_Desc, Ele_Usr_Text AS Inv_Usr_Type, Ele_Action ' +
        'FROM ELEMENT_METRICS WHERE Ele_Name = ''Inventory'' AND Ele_Type = ''Dropdown'') AS INVTYPE ' +
    'WHERE Stop_Number = ' + Convert(Char(10),@Disposition_Number) + ' AND ' +
        'INVTYPE.Ele_Action = ''B'' AND ' +
        'Box_Number *= RESV.Item_Number AND RESV.Item_Type = ''B'' AND ' +
        'BOX.Stop_Number = DISPOSITION_MEMO.Disposition_Number AND ' +
        'BOX.Stop_Date = DISPOSITION_MEMO.Issue_Date'
```

Comment: `select ... from a,b` simply becomes `select ... from a join b`. you'll have to figure out what KIND of join you need (left/right/inner/etc...), on a per-join basis. that'll be less easy.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow this pattern:

```
SELECT c1_1, c1_2, c2_1, c2_2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON c1_1 = c2_1
```

*= is translated to a LEFT JOIN.

See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Alternative_syntaxes.